# How to get Firebase Auth to work on React Native Web(Expo)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am aware that Firebase JS SDK Auth won't work on React Native(Android and iOS)(I have these working natively with Expo browser Auth), but I want to use the JS SDK Auth when its on web, and I don't understand why it doesn't work on React Native Web(Expo), I think it should work in this as its fully on web.

With the code below :

```
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

signInWithPopup(auth, new OAuthProvider("microsoft.com"))
  .then(async (result) => {
        //
  })
  .catch((error) => {
        // 
  });
```

I get this error : e FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).

I have another React App(CRA) where this works, is there something I can install on Expo that maybe is missing in for Firebase Auth?

Answer (score 0):

I initialize my app with persistence like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { environmentData } from "./helpers/environment-url";

let fbApp = initializeApp(environmentData.firebaseConfig);
initializeAuth(fbApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});

export default function App(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
          setUser(null);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

and then sign users in with this function:

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const handleLogIn = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(() => {console.log("user is signed in")})
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Error Logging in: ${error}`)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was this in the setup:

```
 initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
```

I then wrapped in : Works as expected:

```
if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
  try {
    initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
      persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error", e);
  }
}
```